# Change GWT project to Maven Project

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, maven

I've followed instructions http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html
in order to create sample GWT program.

Now I would like to add Maven support to this app ( I would like to use Spring + hibernate support). I have m2e plugin and according to suggestions I turned this project to be Maven project using

Right mouse button->Maven->Convert to Maven project

now when I run project I have the following problem:

```
Loading modules
   com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.StockWatcher
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/sample/StockWatcher.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

any workaround? is there any other methods to intgrate GWT project and Maven 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting fresh, you can use the [GWT maven archetype](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html) that is doing exactly that for you.

Alternatively and if you don't want to get into the technicalities of amending this sample GWT project into a Maven-compliant structure, I would suggest you would look for a Spring+GWT+Hibernate+Maven skeletal implementation or tutorial online. [This one comes up google-first](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/gwt-2-spring-3-jpa-2-hibernate-35.html)

Comment: it doesn't work correct, I have errors in pom.xml and java classes missed references, for example GreatingServiceAsync.java.

Comment: I see what you are saying. If you want to integrate Spring+GWT+Hibernate+Maven I would look for a skeletal implementation or tutorial online. This one comes up google-first: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/gwt-2-spring-3-jpa-2-hibernate-35.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the gwt-maven-plugin and following its documentation. It helped me immensely.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/