# gwt with maven and bootstrap eclipse starter project

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I struggle for a few days now with integrating maven and gwt in eclipse. I was searching web for some ready to import project, but unfortunatelly everything crashed so long.

I am new to gwt. I would like learn it. Earlier I was using maven, spring and playframework with sbt.

I haven't use ant like build tool. But I like it integration between gwt and eclipe (I can click run in super dev mode).

One think is that I do not like in ant, I have to manually download jar and put it in classpath. I think it is unnecessary if maven can do it for me.

I would like also to use this library: [gwtbootstrap3](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3)
I can't handle this on my own.

Can someone of You prepare for me that eclipse project, that I could just import.

Here is my newest `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pl.korbeldaniel.btsp</groupId>
<artifactId>btsp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>btsp</name>

<properties>
    <gwt.version>2.7.0</gwt.version>
    <gwtBootstrap3.version>0.9.1-SNAPSHOT</gwtBootstrap3.version>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>btsp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But I cant run in like native gwt project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a definitely possible. You just have to sift through a ton of documentation to figure it out.

1. You'll need *Google Plugin for eclipse* and the *m2e (Maven Integration for Eclipse) plugin*
2. After you have those, right click on a GWT project-> configure -> convert to Maven Project.
3. Now, to use GwtBootstrap3, all you need to do is add GWT and gwtBootstrap3 as dependencies in your pom. (Details [here](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3/wiki/Initial-Setup)).

If you need any ready to import maven projects, you can clone GwtBootstrap3-demo project from github and run that as a web application. As for learning GWT, [tutorials](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/) are your best option (Pay close attention to UiBinder for GwtBootstrap3).

click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019284/convert-gwt-project-into-maven-gwt-project), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379304/change-gwt-project-to-maven-project) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven) for details about setting everything up.